# Is it possible to set the alert body of uilocalnotification after it is scheduled

Tags: iphone, uilocalnotification

I'm facing an issue with UILocalNotifications. my question is--  Is it possible to set the alert body of uilocalnotification after it is scheduled ??

thanks in advance.

```
-------------------------------------
// scheduling uilocalnotification 
localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc]init];
 NSDate *currDate1 = [defaults objectForKey:@"Default_AlarmTime"];
 localNotification.fireDate = currDate1;
 localNotification.alertBody = @"Alarm";
 localNotification.alertAction = @"View";
 localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
 localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
 localNotification.repeatInterval = NSWeekdayCalendarUnit;
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication]scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];

 // changing alert body of existing local notification


       Arr=[[UIApplication sharedApplication]scheduledLocalNotifications];
        for (int k=0;k<[Arr count];k++) 
        {
            localNotification = [Arr objectAtIndex:k];
            NSLog(@"%@",localNotification.fireDate);
            dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
            [dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]];
            [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"hh:mma"];
            dateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:localNotification.fireDate];
            NSLog(@"%@",dateString); 
            currDate = [defaults objectForKey:@"Default_AlarmTime"];
            NSLog(@"%@",currDate);
            if ([currDate isEqualToString:dateString])
            {

                localNotification.alertBody = @"Haiiiiii";

            }
        }
      ---------------------------
```

Comment: To my knowledge, no.  You either must reschedule it or have the alert body indirect somehow.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this is not possible. To change an already scheduled notification, you have to cancel and completely reschedule it.